# HADOOP_HOME not set while running Azkaban Solo Server?

Tags: hadoop, azkaban

I am trying to run Azkaban Solo Server. Using the steps:[Azkaban Solo Get Started](https://azkaban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getStarted.html)

I am running the start-solo.sh, but can't get anything on localhost:8081. I am trying to figure the issue using the log generated at /azkaban/azkaban-solo-server/build/install/azkaban-solo-server , named like soloServerLog__2020-04-10+03:22:20.out.

It says **"Error: HADOOP_HOME is not set. Hadoop job types will not run properly."**
I already have hadoop installed in my system. Using the command `hadoop version` gives Hadoop 3.0.3, also my **HADOOP_HOME** is set in **.bash_profile** . Do we need to add HADOOP_HOME variable somewhere else in azkaban to run.

Comment: Asuuming you are trying to run Azkaban in the same host as where hadoop is installed! Can you post the output of `echo $HADOOP_HOME`?

Comment: I did figured out the issue, my HADOOP_HOME was not set in .bash_profile file. After adding its working fine . The starting of logs looks like : Using Hadoop from /Users/prakhar.gurawa/hadoop/hadoop-3.0.3 . So its detecting fine. Also the port 8081 was busy so i changed to 9000 . Now things are fine.